# Are incurable diseases curses from the almighty Allah?

Tags: sick, curse

Today I visited a relative's house. She is suffering from cancer.

I have seen him last year during the Eid-ul-fitr. She is almost 70 now. She is so ill that she is looking like a living dead. After seeing her, I became very much unstable mentally.

I am in so much fear that, the question came in my mind.

Are incurable diseases curses from the almighty Allah?

Why people have incurable diseases?

Please explain according to Koran and Hadiths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many infants who died early, there are many 'good' people who died in accidents/sickness and so on. How do we understand this in contrast to the fact that Allah is the most merciful?

---

**Regarding death**
First of all, please read [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/1769/2350). Our life span is already decided at our birth - when we die and how we die are decided.

It is surely Allah that ordained death.

> كَيْفَ تَكْفُرُونَ بِاللَّهِ وَكُنتُمْ أَمْوَاتًا فَأَحْيَاكُمْ ۖ ثُمَّ يُمِيتُكُمْ ثُمَّ يُحْيِيكُمْ ثُمَّ إِلَيْهِ تُرْجَعُونَ
>   Sahih International
>   How can you disbelieve in Allah when you were lifeless and He brought you to life; then He will cause you to die, then He will bring you [back] to life, and then to Him you will be returned.
>   2:28

Death is not the end, you will be given full compensation on the Day of Resurrection.

> كُلُّ نَفْسٍ ذَائِقَةُ الْمَوْتِ ۗ وَإِنَّمَا تُوَفَّوْنَ أُجُورَكُمْ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ ۖ فَمَن زُحْزِحَ عَنِ النَّارِ وَأُدْخِلَ الْجَنَّةَ فَقَدْ فَازَ ۗ وَمَا الْحَيَاةُ الدُّنْيَا إِلَّا مَتَاعُ الْغُرُورِ
>   Sahih International
>   Every soul will taste death, and you will only be given your [full] compensation on the Day of Resurrection. So he who is drawn away from the Fire and admitted to Paradise has attained [his desire]. And what is the life of this world except the enjoyment of delusion.

And the best ending is that

> الَّذِينَ تَتَوَفَّاهُمُ الْمَلَائِكَةُ طَيِّبِينَ ۙ يَقُولُونَ سَلَامٌ عَلَيْكُمُ ادْخُلُوا الْجَنَّةَ بِمَا كُنتُمْ تَعْمَلُونَ
>   Sahih International
>   The ones whom the angels take in death, [being] good and pure; [the angels] will say, "Peace be upon you. Enter Paradise for what you used to do."
>   16:32

---

Now is it Allah's curse? In general no. People are destined to die of different ages, different means.

> يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِن كُنتُمْ فِي رَيْبٍ مِّنَ الْبَعْثِ فَإِنَّا خَلَقْنَاكُم مِّن تُرَابٍ ثُمَّ مِن نُّطْفَةٍ ثُمَّ مِنْ عَلَقَةٍ ثُمَّ مِن مُّضْغَةٍ مُّخَلَّقَةٍ وَغَيْرِ مُخَلَّقَةٍ لِّنُبَيِّنَ لَكُمْ ۚ وَنُقِرُّ فِي الْأَرْحَامِ مَا نَشَاءُ إِلَىٰ أَجَلٍ مُّسَمًّى ثُمَّ نُخْرِجُكُمْ طِفْلًا ثُمَّ لِتَبْلُغُوا أَشُدَّكُمْ ۖ وَمِنكُم مَّن يُتَوَفَّىٰ وَمِنكُم مَّن يُرَدُّ إِلَىٰ أَرْذَلِ الْعُمُرِ لِكَيْلَا يَعْلَمَ مِن بَعْدِ عِلْمٍ شَيْئًا ۚ وَتَرَى الْأَرْضَ هَامِدَةً فَإِذَا أَنزَلْنَا عَلَيْهَا الْمَاءَ اهْتَزَّتْ وَرَبَتْ وَأَنبَتَتْ مِن كُلِّ زَوْجٍ بَهِيجٍ
>   Sahih International
>   O People, if you should be in doubt about the Resurrection, then [consider that] indeed, We created you from dust, then from a sperm-drop, then from a clinging clot, and then from a lump of flesh, formed and unformed - that We may show you. And We settle in the wombs whom We will for a specified term, then We bring you out as a child, and then [We develop you] that you may reach your [time of] maturity. And among you is he who is taken in [early] death, and among you is he who is returned to the most decrepit [old] age so that he knows, after [once having] knowledge, nothing. And you see the earth barren, but when We send down upon it rain, it quivers and swells and grows [something] of every beautiful kind.
>   22:5

In contrast, sudden death is not good. When you are expecting your death it is not a bad thing.

> Alqamah narrated:
>   "I heard Abdullah saying: 'I heard the Messenger of Allah saying: "The believer's soul seeps out, and I do not like the death like that of a donkey." They said: "And what is the death of a donkey?" He said: "A sudden death."] (Da'if)
>
> حَدَّثَنَا أَحْمَدُ بْنُ الْحَسَنِ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا مُسْلِمُ بْنُ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا حُسَامُ بْنُ الْمِصَكِّ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو مَعْشَرٍ، عَنْ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، عَنْ عَلْقَمَةَ، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ عَبْدَ اللَّهِ، يَقُولُ سَمِعْتُ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم يَقُولُ ‏"‏ إِنَّ نَفْسَ الْمُؤْمِنِ تَخْرُجُ رَشْحًا وَلاَ أُحِبُّ مَوْتًا كَمَوْتِ الْحِمَارِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قِيلَ وَمَا مَوْتُ الْحِمَارِ قَالَ ‏"‏ مَوْتُ الْفَجْأَةِ
>   Jami` at-Tirmidhi 980

---

**Regarding sickness**

Sickness is an expiation of sin (for believers)

> Narrated Ibn `Abbas:
>   Allah's Messenger (PBUH) entered upon sick man to pay him a visit, and said to him, "Don't worry, Allah willing, (your sickness will be) an expiation for your sins." The man said, "No, it is but a fever that is boiling within an old man and will send him to his grave." On that, the Prophet (PBUH) said, "Then yes, it is so."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا إِسْحَاقُ، حَدَّثَنَا خَالِدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، عَنْ خَالِدٍ، عَنْ عِكْرِمَةَ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ ـ رضى الله عنهما ـ أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم دَخَلَ عَلَى رَجُلٍ يَعُودُهُ فَقَالَ ‏"‏ لاَ بَأْسَ طَهُورٌ إِنْ شَاءَ اللَّهُ ‏"‏‏.‏ فَقَالَ كَلاَّ بَلْ حُمَّى تَفُورُ عَلَى شَيْخٍ كَبِيرٍ كَيْمَا تُزِيرَهُ الْقُبُورَ‏.‏ قَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ فَنَعَمْ إِذًا
>   Sahih al-Bukhari 5662
>
> Narrated `Abdullah:
>   I visited the Prophet (PBUH) during his ailments and he was suffering from a high fever. I said, "You have a high fever. Is it because you will have a double reward for it?" He said, "Yes, for no Muslim is afflicted with any harm but that Allah will remove his sins as the leaves of a tree fall down."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ يُوسُفَ، حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ، عَنِ الأَعْمَشِ، عَنْ إِبْرَاهِيمَ التَّيْمِيِّ، عَنِ الْحَارِثِ بْنِ سُوَيْدٍ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ أَتَيْتُ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فِي مَرَضِهِ وَهْوَ يُوعَكُ وَعْكًا شَدِيدًا، وَقُلْتُ إِنَّكَ لَتُوعَكُ وَعْكًا شَدِيدًا‏.‏ قُلْتُ إِنَّ ذَاكَ بِأَنَّ لَكَ أَجْرَيْنِ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏ "‏ أَجَلْ مَا مِنْ مُسْلِمٍ يُصِيبُهُ أَذًى، إِلاَّ حَاتَّ اللَّهُ عَنْهُ خَطَايَاهُ، كَمَا تَحَاتُّ وَرَقُ الشَّجَرِ
>   Sahih al-Bukhari 5647

Sickness is a severe test for one's religion

> Hadith - Al-Tirmidhi 1562, Narrated Sa'd
>   When the Prophet  was asked which people suffered the greatest affliction, he replied, "The prophets, then those who come next to them, then those who come next to them. A man is afflicted in keeping his religion. If he is firm in his religion his trial is severe, but if there is weakness in his religion it is made light for him, and it continues like that till he walks on the earth having no sin."

And a believer will be compensated for the affliction.

> Hadith - Al-Tirmidhi #1570, Narrated Jabir ibn Abdullah
>   Allah's Messenger  said, "On the Day of Resurrection, when people who have suffered affliction are given their reward, those who are healthy will wish their skins had been cut to pieces with scissors when they were in the world."

---

**To conclude**
The message is that death is not in our control but Allah's. What we can do is to be pious and patient, and Allah will compensate us with what we deserve. Allah is the just, don't worry.

And Allah knows the best.

---

**Note**
Not all hadith cited are considered as Sahih.